# Virtualbox with Linux mint running slow possibly because of high disk usage

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint

So I have Linux Mint installed on Virtualbox with Windows 10 as host, but it runs slow, it takes a while to boot up and there is occasional lag, and some things can take have a few second delay while opening (like browsers).

I tried different GPU settings, tried giving it a dedicated GPU, same result, tried changing the graphics controller, same result, enabling 3D acceleration, same result (although maybe these stuff improved things a bit), and it's not due to my power plan.

Likewise tried giving it more RAM (right now about 6GB), and more cores, same result (although maybe it improved things a bit).

So I opened task manager on the host system and it showed that whenever the guest machine does something (including the system booting up), the disk usage jumps to almost 100%.

Comment: How fast is the hard drive (5400 rpm or 7200 rpm)?  Does it need to be defragmented? (this is normally automatic).

Comment: @John It doesn't need to be defragmented, I checked that. Also it is 5400 rpm.

Comment: 5400 rpm hard drives are very slow. That is why.

Comment: I mean, I never had a performance problem otherwise with the drive. Also RPM alone doesn't determine the speed of a drive. Edit: If what you say about VMs being prune to it, then it might be true.

Comment: RPM plays a large part in performance. The machine may be in segments which will exacerbate the issue even if Windows is not ready to defragment. Move the machine folder to a USB drive, restart, and copy the machine folder back. Still , the drive is too slow. I stopped using 5400-rpm drives in about 2004 in favour of faster drives for virtual machines

Answer (score 0):

> So I have Linux Mint installed on Virtualbox with Windows 10 as host,
> but it runs slow, it takes a while to boot up and there is occasional
> lag, and some things can take have a few second delay while opening
> (like browsers).

Virtual machines are very prone to lagging with slow hard drives. You have confirmed a 5400-rpm hard drive and that is too slow for any virtual machine activity. This is why you see the high disk activity.

7200-rpm is much better and a fast SSD drive is best.